# Inverse of a sum of two easy matrices

Tags: operators, eigenvalue

Let $A$ be a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix and $I$ the identity matrix.

Given the linear equation

$$
y = A(A + \sigma^2I)^{-1} x
$$

Write $A$ in terms of its eigenvectors $|u_i\rangle$, 
$$
A=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i|u_i\rangle\langle u_i|
$$ 
and assume 
$$
x = \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i |u_i\rangle
$$

How can one prove that 
$$
y = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\gamma_i\lambda_i}{\lambda_i + \sigma^2}|u_i\rangle
$$

I have been trying to use the [matrix inversion lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity), but I can't get the result. Is there something fundamental that I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Given $A$ in the above form, and assuming the eigenvectors are normalized, $(A+\sigma^2I)^{-1}$ is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\lambda_i+\sigma^2}\left|u_i\right>\left<u_i\right|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that
\begin{align} 
(A+\sigma^2 I) &= \sum_i \lambda_i |u_i\rangle \langle u_i| + \sigma^2\sum_i|u_i\rangle \langle u_i|\\
&=\sum_i (\lambda_i +\sigma^2)|u_i\rangle \langle u_i|
\end{align}
It's diagonal with respect to $|u_i\rangle$, so the inverse is simply,

\begin{align} 
(A+\sigma^2 I)^{-1} &=\sum_i \frac{1}{(\lambda_i +\sigma^2)}|u_i\rangle \langle u_i|
\end{align}
Using the vector decomposition $x = \sum_i \gamma_i|u_i\rangle$, we have
\begin{align}
(A+\sigma^2 I)^{-1}x = \sum_i \frac{\gamma_i}{(\lambda_i +\sigma^2)}|u_i\rangle 
\end{align}
and so
\begin{align} 
A(A+\sigma^2 I)^{-1}x &=\sum_i \frac{\gamma_i}{(\lambda_i +\sigma^2)}A|u_i\rangle\\
&= \sum_i \frac{\gamma_i\lambda_i}{(\lambda_i +\sigma^2)}|u_i\rangle 
\end{align}

Comment: Gosh! First line is a saver... I did not note that! Thanks Olaf